# Calling Server method by jquery is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a confirmdialog, where i want to call a simple method from the jquery. 
 When i click on the 'No', it should call the server method. 
 I Used:

```js
function ConfirmDialog() {
        $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
.html('<div><h4>' + 'Do you wanto to see previous data' + '?</h4></div>')
.dialog({
    modal: true, title: 'Carry forward!', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
    width: 'auto', resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        Yes: function () {
            //                $(obj).removeAttr('onclick');
            //                $(obj).parents('.Parent').remove();
             <%= ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnConfrm, Nothing) %>                           
            $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>Yes</i></h1>');
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        No: function () {
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "MPR_Fill.aspx/dataNotCarryForwarding",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                failure: function(response) {

                    }
                });                      
            $('body').append('<h1>Confirm Dialog Result: <i>No</i></h1>');
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
```

Method is:

```vb
Public Sub dataNotCarryForwarding()

    Response.Write("In dataNotCarryForwarding()")

End Sub
Public Sub dataCarryForwarding()

    gvCustomers.Visible = True
    fillGridWithCarryForwarding()
End Sub
```

And the button is:

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnConfrm" runat="server" Text="View" ForeColor="Black" Width="80px"
                            CssClass="button" Height="30px" ValidationGroup="btn" OnClientClick="ConfirmDialog(); return false;" OnClick="dataCarryForwarding" />
<asp:Button ID="btn_show" runat="server" Text="View" ForeColor="Black" Width="80px"
                            CssClass="button" Height="30px" ValidationGroup="btn" OnClick="fillGridWithoutCarryForwarding" />
```

`No:function()` for directly call the `dataNotCarryForwarding()` is not working.

Comment: what you mean by `ajax is not working.`. what is the error you are getting

Comment: @Sajidkhan You are declaring your `Ajax` as type "POST" yet you post no data to the server

Comment: you could add  , error: function(jqXHR, textStatus,  errorThrown )  after success to get more info... and print response when "failure"

Comment: In C#, you need to add the tag `[WebMethod]` above the server methods that are accessible to ajax. Something similar may be necessary in VB as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Imports System.Web.Services` and add the `<WebMethod>` attribute to your codebehind function:

```
<WebMethod>
Public Sub dataNotCarryForwarding()

    Response.Write("In dataNotCarryForwarding()")

End Sub
```